# insert data from one table to another in ruby active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class RetailerLogs < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class RetailerLogsNew < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'retailer_logs_new'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

what i'm getting is you are trying to save the data in two table .
To do this no need to write any complex thing .

```
@retailer_logs = RetailerLogs.create(retailer_logs_params) ## what ever params you are saving 

@retailer_logs_new = RetailerLogsNew.create(retailer_logs_params)
```

and then `redirect to` where-ever you want

Hope this help you!!

Comment: @Shanto CV: Let us know if the answers work for you ?